# MySQL query to count total number of orders made by hour returns always 1 for each hour

Tags: mysql, datetime, count, hour

I have following query which is supposed to count the total number of orders made by hour.

The problem is that total number is always 1 per hour. I have similar query for weekdays which works just fine. What is wrong or missing in the following query?

```
SELECT COUNT(`Orderno`) as 'totals', EXTRACT(HOUR FROM `order_datetime`) as 'hour'
FROM `orders`
GROUP BY `order_datetime`
```

Results are

```
totals hour
1      0
1      1
1      2
...
```

Comment: `GROUP BY order_datetime` will only group rows together if they have the exact same time, not the same hour.

Comment: You also have some quoting issues, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(`Orderno`) as 'totals', EXTRACT(HOUR FROM `order_datetime`) as   'hour'
FROM `orders`
GROUP BY `order_datetime`,EXTRACT(HOUR FROM `order_datetime`)
```

Try it

Comment: Great, thanks! Just a small modification to your suggestion made it work: GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM `order_datetime`)

Answer (score 0):

```
group by hour(order_datetime)
```

should do it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13963322)

Comment: @zinking Looks good to me... It would be nice if it had a bit more explanation, but it *does* attempt to answer the question.